# Auto Scaling Group launch config changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I wonder if there is a simple way or best practices on how to ensure all instances within an AutoScaling group have been launched with the current launch-configuration of that AutoScaling group.

To give an example, imagine an auto-scaling group called `www-asg` with 4 desired instances running webservers behind an ELB. I want to change the AMI or the userdata used to start instances of this auto-scaling group. So I create a new launch configuration `www-cfg-v2` and update `www-asg` to use that.

```
# create new launch config
as-create-launch-config www-cfg-v2 \
    --image-id 'ami-xxxxxxxx' --instance-type m1.small \
    --group web,asg-www --user-data "..."

# update my asg to use new config
as-update-auto-scaling-group www-asg --launch-configuration www-cfg-v2
```

By now all 4 running instances still use the old launch configuration. I wonder if there is a simple way of replacing all running instances with new instances to enforce the new configuration, **but** always ensure that the minimum of instances is kept running.

My current way of achieving this is as follows..

1. save list of current running instances for given autoscaling group
2. temporarily increase the number of desired instances +1
3. wait for the new instance to be available
4. terminate one instance from the list via

   ```
   as-terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group i-XXXX \
       --no-decrement-desired-capacity --force
   ```
5. wait for the replacement instance to be available
6. if more than 1 instance is left repeat with 4.
7. terminate last instance from the list via

   ```
   as-terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group i-XXXX \
       --decrement-desired-capacity --force
   ```
8. done, all instances should now run with same launch config

I have mostly automated this procedure but I feel there must be some better way of achieving the same goal. Anyone knows a better more efficient way?

mathias

Also posted this question in the official [AWS EC2 Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=135513).

Comment: Just wondering, have you found an alternative way of doing this? I'm pretty much doing the exact same thing you describe above.

Comment: @CocoaNoob: no... but I also haven't changed launch configs for quiet some time by now. But here is the script I wrote for rolling changes: https://gist.github.com/muhqu/76264d73d42edbb75263

Comment: @muhqu Have you found an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: @froi no. Still doing it exactly as I wrote it... :-(

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a lot different, but you could:

1. create the new LC
2. create a new ASG using the new LC
3. scale down the old ASG
4. delete the old asg and LC

I do deployments this way, and it's in my experience to roll from one ASG to another, rather than having to jump back and forth. But as I noted, it's not a huge difference.

It might be worth looking at:  https://github.com/Netflix/asgard , which is a Netflix OSS tool for managing autoscaling groups. I ended up not using it, but it's pretty interesting nonetheless.

Comment: one drawback of creating a new ASG is that you also have to recreate any scaling policies (e.g. alarms triggering scale-up/down operations). The way Netflix uses ASGs as deployment units is an interesting approach... but I think I stick to a fixed number of auto-scaling-groups and changing their launch-configs if something changes. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I don't use any scaling policies, and just have fixed size ASGs, but if you want to scale dynamically this approach would add complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know but I thought I would share my approach.

I change the launch config for an ASG, I then launch the same number of instances as are currently in the ASG, as they become available (automated testing) they are attached to the ASG. once the machines have been added our deployment system updates our varnish loadbalancer(s) to use the new instances and the old instances are terminated.

All of the above is automated and a full site scale switch takes about 5 minutes depending on the launch time.

incase you are wondering, we use SNS to handle updating varnish when instances are added or removed or in the case of our loadbalancers scaling (which almost never happens) the deployment system will update our route53 config instead.

I think that pretty much covers everything

Comment: So you're using ASG without ELB and run varnish (on its own EC2 instances) for HTTP load-balancing? Why not ELB? ..you have to do health-checking etc on your own, right?

Comment: Thats right, its a very "special" application with lots of complex routing to 7ish backends depending whats being accessed. so varnish handles the health checking and backend selection.

for our other applications we use ELBs and apart from SNS the same approach is used, servers are manually added to the ASG once ready for service.